# Calculus ll, Help checking please

Tags: calculus

I've been trying to solve this calculus ll exercise and I have been having problems, I wanted to know if you can examine it and tell me what you think, Is it wrong? Is it right?, What am I doing wrong?, How you would do it?, anything helps. Hope you can help and thank you very much in advance

1. Is continuous and derivable for the function $f(x)=\frac{\cos x}{x}$ in $[1/2,3/2]$, determine its absolute ends and use the "Comparison Property" to find upper and lower dimensions for the area of the region enclosed by the graph of f and the x-axis, in the given interval

How I resolved the problem, please tell me how I did:
[image]

I'm sure you guys already know but the links are imagines, hope its not much of an inconvenience and you can still help.

Comment: This looks good to me.